# GWT and struts2 exception

Tags: java, jsp, gwt, struts2

I'm getting the exception:

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jasper.JasperException: File "/struts-tags" not found

at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:51)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:409)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:160)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:386)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:449)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1396)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:130)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:255)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:103)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:185)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:347)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspC.processFile(JspC.java:1192)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspC.execute(JspC.java:1341)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalJspC.main(LocalJspC.java:35)
Error while executing: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\javaw.exe -classpath /C:/Users/...

here is my login.jsp file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=windows-1255"
pageEncoding="windows-1255"%>
<%@ taglib  prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta name="gwt:module" content="org.apache.struts.gwt.Main/org.apache.struts.gwt.Main">
<title>login</title>
</head>
<body>
<script language="javascript"    src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/org.apache.struts.gwt.Main/gwt.js">
 </script>  
    <s:form action="/login">
            <s:textfield label="email address" key="emailAddress" />
            <s:password label="password" key="password" />
    <s:submit />
  </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

I've downloaded the struts2gwtplugin-1.02.jar

How it's possible to use struts 2 and GWT?

Comment: Are you sure this is a problem with gwt?  Maybe you have not packaged your web app with all its necessary dependencies (e.g. some struts 2 jar containing your taglibs)?

Comment: on it's own without using GWT it's working fine

Comment: The exception is when I'm trying to deploy the project